# Java generics - purpose of wildcard except for lower bounds?

Tags: java, generics

What is the purpose of using a wildcard for unbounded or upper-bounded generics?  More specifically:

Why would I say `public static void foo(List<?> bar)` instead of `public static <E> void foo(List<E> bar)`?

Why would I say `public static void foo(List<? extends Baz> bar)` instead of `public static <E extends Baz> void foo(List<E> bar)`?

Comment: Conciseness, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The versions with a wildcard are preferred. If a parameter has type `List<?>` it is clear that any `List` will be accepted. If any `List` is accepted, there's no reason to give the type parameter a name, so writing `<E>` would just be clutter. On the other hand, if the type parameter appears twice in the signature, then you cannot use wildcards. For example, this signature needs a type parameter.

```
public static <E> List<E> combineLists(List<E> list1, List<E> list2)
```

Actually in that example it would probably be better if the arguments had type `List<? extends E>` (the only way to do that without wildcards would be to have three type parameters, a total mess).

In Effective Java, it is recommended that even if the type parameter is needed in the body of the method, you should prefer the version of the signature with a wildcard, and write a private helper method to make this possible. For example:

```
public static void swapFirstAndLast(List<?> list) {
    helper(list);
}

private static <E> void helper(List<E> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    E e = list.get(0);
    list.set(0, list.get(size - 1)); // These lines would not be possible
    list.set(size - 1, e);           // If the type of list were List<?>
}
```

Comment: Everywhere except for the actual type parameter you can place a wildcard.  This means that, while this is valid syntax:  `public static <E> List<?> combineLists(List<?> list1, List<?> list2)`, you're going to hate yourself for trying to implement that.

Comment: @Makoto You could write it, but it would be less safe, as you would not be sure any of the lists had any type in common, whereas `<? extends E>` would ensure an upper boundary E, making this illegal: `combineList(asList(""), asList(0))`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not ever going to refer to `E` in the code that follows, there is no need to declare it.

Reduces programmer memory strain.

Comment: Yep, pretty much exactly what I was going to say.  A generic type is there to empower you to DO something with it, not really as syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

If the type of the list is decided at runtime, then you will need to use wildcards.

The following program will print a `List<String>` if run with any command-line arguments; otherwise it will print a `List<Number>`:

```
public class Test {

    public static List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
    public static List<Number> listOfNumbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4.5);

    public static List<?> getListOfUnknown(boolean arg) {
        if(arg) return listOfStrings;
        else return listOfNumbers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getListOfUnknown(args.length > 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the OP's line of reasoning, you would do something like: `public <T extends Object> List<T> getListOfUnknown(boolean arg)`.  Not that I'm recommending that.

Comment: @asteri but then you would need to call `<String>getListOfUnknown` or `<Number>getListOfUnknown`, as `T` needs to be known at compile-time.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  Sorry, I just read the method signature, not the method body.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The official tutorial for [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) already explained well enough.

> ... the type parameter T is used only once. The return type doesn't depend on the type parameter, nor does any other argument to the method (in this case, there simply is only one argument). This tells us that the type argument is being used for polymorphism; its only effect is to allow a variety of actual argument types to be used at different invocation sites. If that is the case, one should use wildcards. ...
>
> Generic methods allow type parameters to be used to express dependencies among the types of one or more arguments to a method and/or its return type. **If there isn't such a dependency, a generic method should not be used.**